# Intellisense expected a ';' with a multi line string literal

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, stringstream, stdstring, string-literals

I'm trying to create a linux man page for my program. I'm using getopt to parse several command line arguments and flags, one of which may be 'h', which should print the man page then exit.

I'm programming in VS 2013, and this nagging little error won't go away. According to intellisense, a semicolon is expected on the line that says "-c, --container\n". From my understanding of multi-line string literals, you only place a semicolon after the body of text you want to put inside a std::string, which is why this is particularly frustrating.

Below is my code:

```
case 'h':{
        string out;
        out = "NAME\n"
            "\tblah.\n"
            "SYNOPSIS\n"
            "\tmore text\n"
            "\tprogram (­-h | ­­--help)"
            "DESCRIPTION\n"
            "\ttext text text\n"
            "\tAI. mpre text\n"
            "\ttext\n"
            "\ttext.\n"
            "OPTIONS\n"
            "-h, --­­help\n"
            "\tPrint this help screen and exit.\n"
            ­"-c, --­­container\n"
            "\ttext\n"
            "\ttext\n"
            ­"text\n"
            "\ttext.\n"
            ­"-v, --­­verbose N\n"
            "\tdescriptions\n"
            "\tstatistics.\n"
            ­"-d, --­­debug\n"
            "\ttext\n";
        ss << out;
        cout << ss.str();
        cout.flush();
        exit(0);
        break;
    }
```

How can I fix this particularly annoying error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I copy-and-paste your source code, I get some odd non-printable characters, including some on the `"-c, --­­container\n"` line. They appear to be UTF-8 encoded `SOFT HYPHEN` characters (the UTF-8 encoding may be an artifact of how you copy-and-pasted the code into your web browser). Filter those out and you should be ok.

Comment: What text editor are you using to see these characters?

Comment: @JackKnudson: No text editor; I just copy the text from my web browser and then paste it through a command on Linux that shows non-printable characters. If I view the file in `vim`, the soft hyphens look like ordinary hyphen characters. There are several of them; the ones inside string literals don't bother the compiler, but they're undoubtedly not what you want.